# Python: Attempting to replace one element in a 2D list replaces all the elements at a certain point in every list.

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

This my code.

```
def spiral(length):
    half = length//2
    matrix = [[None]*length]*length
    matrix[half][half]= 1
    return matrix

spiral(5)
```

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not very familiar with Python. When I attempt to replace a single element, I end up replacing the elements of every list.

```
def spiral(length):
    half = length//2
    matrix = [[None]*length]*length
    matrix[half][half]= 1
    return matrix

spiral(5)
```

My current output is:

```
   [[None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None]]
```

My intended output is:

```
   [[None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, 1, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

List multiplication creates several references to the same list. So when you change one, all recieve the changes.

To fix this, you can use list comprehension.

Change this:

```
matrix = [[None]*length]*length
```

To this:

```
matrix = [[None]*length for _ in range(length)]
```

More about list comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: `[None]*length` does not need to replaced with the a comprehension